# jquery.ie6hover.js confilcts with jQueryUI and crashes IE6

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

I have a website that's using **jquery.ie6hover.js** (https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-ie6hover)
And I've just updated to latest version of **jQueryUI** (1.9.1)
This combination crashes the browser when opening the page in IE6.

It's crashing when calling:

```
$.ie6hover();
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umhxQ/

I'm testing IE6 using Virtual Box, with Windows XP SP3.

Any ideas how to prevent IE6 from crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon [**"ie7.js"**](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which seemed to do the trick.

It contains a fix for the hover bug in ie6 (without jQueryUI conflicts)
And jquery.ie6hover.js is no longer needed!

Comment: +1 because ie7.js is a great little script, albeit maybe overkill if all you want is to fix the hover.

Answer (score 1):

ie7.js - the one you found already - is a great script. It's a bit overkill if all you want to do is fix the hover, because ie7.js fixes loads of stuff. That's great, but if you don't need all the features, then you may be slowing down the browser unnecessarily.

If all you want is to fix the hover, my preferred script is [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html), which is the one I used to recommend for this.

(when I say "used to recommend", there's nothing wrong with it; it's because these days I don't really recommend supporting IE6 at all. But if you do need to support it, then Whatever:Hover is what I'd use)